# Update where exists delete row where doesn't

Tags: sql, postgresql, delete-row

I can update fine and I can delete fine, but I want to do both at once.

I have a table ORIG like this, column names are

```
ref,fname,lname,add1,add2,add3,add4

A1  a  b  c  d  h  j
S2  f  d  s  e  y  t
B3  j  f  s  e  o  p
```

Where the first column is unique

then another table DATA like this

```
ref,fname,lname,add1,add2

A1  b  c  d  e
B3  k  g  h  t
```

I want to update the first table using the second and delete any rows that don't have the unique

So the end result needs to be table ORIG like below

```
A1  b  c  d  e  h  j
B3  k  g  h  t  o  p
```

Am I able to accomplish this in one go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might approach this using CTEs:

```
with u as (
      update orig
          set b = d.b, . . .
          from data d
          where d.a = orig.a
      returning *
     )
delete from orig
    where not exists (select 1 from u where u.a = d.a);
```

The first CTE updates the rows.  The second one does the delete.

Comment: Is there any benefit doing `not exists (select 1 from u where u.a = d.a` vs `d.a not in (select u.a from u)`?

Comment: Gives me a syntax error ERROR:  syntax error at or near "from"
LINE 8: delete from orig
               ^

Comment: @Kilisi: that's a typo in the answer. You need to remove the `,` after the CTE

Comment: @DanielBickler . . . I don't recommend using `not in` with subqueries, because the semantics of `NULL` handling is counterintuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery for this:

```
delete
from orig o
where not exists (
        select 1
        from data d
        where d.col1 = o.col1
        )
```